# Rename file with file's date in CMD

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I think I've bitten off a lot more than I can chew.

I'm a court reporter, working in the Minnesota court system. We've developed a new policy for filing our electronic notes, as so many reporters are no longer printing to paper notes. Different brands of reporting machines create files with different naming conventions, and we want to standardize the names so someone in district administration can find the right notes easily if we are not around.

So we want to rename FILE.001, FILE.002, and 20151018-082815.sgstn, for example, to the date the file was created. The sgstn file, of course, has a unique name, but the ubiquitous writers that create FILE.* files really need renaming, and standardization will help all. I'm creating a CMD file that will also poll for the judge's name and the writer brand, so anyone pulling the notes out of storage will find exactly what they're looking for: "2015-10-18 Judge Jones, Stentura writer.001"

I've found plenty of solutions for renaming files with TODAY's date and time, but we want to rename them with THEIR OWN date and time.

I'm working as a standard user in Windows 7 Pro and do not have the option of installing third-party software. Windows allows individual users to set their preferred date style, and dbenham and others here have shown me how to get that style from the registry:

```
:: For REG.EXE 3.0 (Windows XP) and later versions
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN (
  'REG QUERY "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate'
  ) DO (SET sShortDate=%%A)
Echo %sShortDate%
```

That will return yyyy-MM-dd or d-M-yy or whatever the user has chosen.

And then I can test to see what the contents are of the different pieces of the string:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/-" %%A in ("%sShortDate%") do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%D in ("%%A") do (
        set Part1=%%D
    )
    for /f "tokens=1" %%D in ("%%B") do (
        set Part2=%%D
    )
    for /f "tokens=1" %%D in ("%%C") do (
        set Part3=%%D
    )
)
echo Part1 = %Part1%
echo Part2 = %Part2%
echo Part3 = %Part3%
```

But this is all getting really unwieldy, and I'm only halfway there after a solid 24 hours of reading here and elsewhere. Is there really no way in Windows, at the CMD prompt or in any command-line-available tool, to get the date of a file in a predictable format and to use that date?

Can anyone take pity on me and give us a less cumbersome means of finding out what the user's particular system thinks the date should be formatted as and thus consistently rename all files that get dropped on the CMD shortcut?

Finally, this is my first post here. All constructive criticism gladly accepted. Seriously.

-- Timothy J. McGowan

Edited to add:
Maybe I've been overthinking this. It's the user's hive in the registry I'm polling for the date format. We ought to be able to write to our own hive from the command line; right?

So I could read the user's preferred date format, save that to a variable, force the date format I want to use, process the files, and then reset the user's date format. Right? Worth a shot.

I'll report back if it works, but any more comments are quite welcome!

Comment: If it is possible to do so, this would be much more reliable if implemented in vbscript or powershell or, well, pretty much any actual programming language.  While you *can* do a lot of stuff in batch, it wasn't really designed for it.  (I suggest vbscript and powershell in particular mainly because they are built into Windows.)

Comment: Thanks, Harry. Haven't progressed to VBScript or PowerShell yet. Facile in PerfectScript, but I've never used Word, just WordPerfect. And I doubt I can talk an entire branch of the government into using a different word processor. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this isn't a full answer to the question I asked, but it should be all I need to get a predictable date.

It's possible to save the user's preferred date style from the Registry, force one you want to work with, conduct your business, and then return the user's preferred date style (assuming they don't cancel the batch file in the middle of the run).

The output is messy but it simply proves the concept works.

```
@echo off
:: replace and then restore date style in Windows registry.

:: find current date style; save to environment variable OriginalsShortDate
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN (
  'REG QUERY "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate'
  ) DO SET OriginalsShortDate=%%A

:: display current date style as reflected by date of this CMD/BAT file
echo Current date style to be saved:  %OriginalsShortDate%
echo Looks like this:
dir %0
echo Press any key to set yyyy-MM-dd date style
pause

:: force preferred date style and hide success message
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d yyyy-MM-dd /f >nul

:: prove it's changed
:: //////////// here's where you do your business \\\\\\\\\\\\
echo Check file's date now.
dir %0
echo (Your Windows task bar may not reflect change immediately.)
echo.
echo Press any key to set MM-dd-yy date style
pause

:: force next style
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d MM-dd-yy /f >nul

:: prove it's changed
echo Check file's date now; it will be in MM-dd-yy format.
dir %0
echo Press any key to return date format to your preferred style.
pause

:: return to user's original setting
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d %OriginalsShortDate% /f >nul

:: prove it's back to normal
dir %0
echo Your original, presumably preferred, date style has been reset.
echo Give your Windows task bar some time to update.
```

Answer (score 1):

A first idea :

Use the delimiters to get the file date or name or extension

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.*) do (
  set "$FileName=%%~na"
  set "$FileExtension=%%~xa"
  set "$FileDate=%%~ta"
  set "$FileDate=!$FileDate:/=-!"
  echo !$FileDate!-!$FileName!!$FileExtension!)
```

**EDIT I**

To get the date in YYYY-MM-DD :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.*) do (
  set "$FileName=%%~na"
  set "$FileExtension=%%~xa"
  set "$FileDate=%%~ta"
  set "$FileDate=!$FileDate:/=-!"
  set "$FileDate=!$FileDate:~6,4!-!$FileDate:~3,2!-!$FileDate:~0,2!"
  echo !$FileDate!-!$FileName!!$FileExtension!)
```

Comment: Thanks, SachaDee. I was heading there next.

Oops. Didn't know Enter would post the message.

Comment: I was out when they explained the dollar sign. I don't see it under the FOR help. I'll try SetLocal next.

The problem with this is that, as an experiment, I have my system's date set to display as d-M-yy. That makes today 18-10-15. Messed up, yes, but I'm exaggerating on purpose. I normally use yyyy-MM-dd, but most people use dd-MM-yyyy. So I need to parse the current user's registry to find out where the year, month, and day is in their setup, and then rename the file to yyyy-MM-dd plus the rest.

Comment: @TimothyJ.McGowan - the dollar sign here is meaningless and just part of the variable name.